# Hierarchical column structures in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I create a Dataframe like this

```
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('id',), ('position', 'x'), ('position', 'y')])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(1, 2, 3)], columns=i)
```

This gives the following output:

```
   id position
  NaN        x  y
0   1        2  3
```

I am able to access the subdataframe for position now with `df.position` which yields

```
   x  y
0  2  3
```

or for example I can get the position with `df.position.x[0]`

However, I am not able to directly use `df.id[0]`. I guess the reason is that one of the column levels is set to NaN.

Is there any  possibility in this scenario to have the same behavior for `df.position.x` and `df.id`? (apparently `df.id` is a dataframe)
Also is it possible to get rid of the `NaN` level ?

Answer (score 0):

`df.position.x.[0]` is equivalent to `df.position['x'][0]`

So, to select the value you want you would need to do:

```
df.id[float('nan')][0]
```

or better:

```
df.loc[0, ('id', float('nan'))]
```

output: `1`

Comment: Thank you, but its not about access more about the behavior at all, is it somehow possible to avoid this? BR

Comment: what happens when you run `df.position[0]`? You get an error. Why would you expect any different from `df.id[0]`? Having a NaN doesn't mean you have one less level ;)

Comment: yes I know thats my question basically can I have one less level for the ID column

Comment: No. The levels are global on the whole dataframe. You can't have columns with only one level while the others have more.

Comment: Do you know whats the motivation behind this ?  You could write this down as an answer if you like.

Comment: I'm also curious what would be the best workaround in such a scenario, maybe you have an idea. cheers

Comment: @jrsm I guess this is the most logical. The real question is why would you have variable levels?

Comment: To have easy access to different columns, e.g.  i  could do s.th. like ` x = df.position[df.id == 4]`, this doesn't work unfortunately.